# Select elements where previous siblings children match something

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```css
.header .cell.open~.header .cell {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 1</div>
  <div class="row">Content 2</div>
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 2 (This should be yellow)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 3</div>
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 3 (This should be yellow)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Bartude/pen/VwgvPbx

Basically I want all the header cells which contain a preceding header cell to have a certain style. In this case, I need Header 2 and Header 3 to have a yellow background.

I tried this without the child `.cell` elements in the HTML and it worked, but I need it to work like I have above.

EDIT_____

Here is a second example of this snippet, but slightly more close to what I need:

```css
.header .cell.open~.header .cell {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 1</div>
  <div class="row">Content 2</div>
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell close">Header 2 (This should be yellow)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 3</div>
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 3 (This should be yellow)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

In this case, I would only like Header 3 to be highlighted with yellow. Not sure if this is even possible since there doesn't seem to be an immediate preceding sibling selector.

Comment: `.header ~ .header .cell` ?

Answer (score 1):

`.cell.open` is not a sibling of `.header` so you can target all `.header` elements having `.cell.open` as inner elements with `:has()` ([not yet supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has) on Firefox, so far)

```css
.header:has(.cell.open) ~ .header .cell {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 1</div>
  <div class="row">Content 2</div>
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 2 (This should be yellow)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 3</div>
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell open">Header 3 (This should be yellow)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I know the answer to this, but is there no way to do immediate preceding sibling? For example, if Header 2 was changed to `cell close`, then I would like only Header 3 to be with a yellow background

Comment: I edited my question to add this second example